# routing on aws - combining multiple services

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, routes, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have some resources exposed in different services in AWS. Some files on s3, some rest API on beanstalk.  Now I would like to serve them under the same domain mycompany.com

```
/, /assets/ -> s3  
/* -> beanstalk
```

What's the 'official' way to do it? Cloud front? Route 53? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to combine different endpoints under a single host/domain, you probably want to use Cloudfront and an application load balancer.

Cloudfront can map paths - like /assets/ - to S3 buckets.  You would then have your default origin point to your load balancer.

If you are using an application load balancer, you can further route traffic - ALB supports both host and path based routing, so /api/ could go to one target group with a set of instances, /app/ another, etc.